# UICollectionView inside TableCell with dynamic data is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm still until now want to code collectionview(content buttons ) inside tableCell (content a textLabel and sometime TextField or a collectionview) and load dynamic data from firebase but I nothing is happing inside the collection view ! Please Help me . this is my code and the screen of my App. Please helps

this is the screenshot of the app 
[image: this is the screenshot of the app]

Comment: link does not work :(

Comment: Please add the code part too.